# How exactly do dividend reinvestment plans (DRIPs) work?

Tags: investing, stocks, terminology, dividends, dividend-reinvestment

And where can I find out what companies offer them? Are there good resources for information on these plans?

Answer (score 9):

I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_reinvestment_plan) offers a very good explanation:

> A dividend reinvestment program or dividend reinvestment plan (DRIP) is an equity investment option offered directly from the underlying company. The investor does not receive quarterly dividends directly as cash; instead, the investor's dividends are directly reinvested in the underlying equity. The investor must still pay tax annually on his or her dividend income, whether it is received or reinvested.
>
> This allows the investment return from dividends to be immediately invested for the purpose of price appreciation and compounding, without incurring brokerage fees or waiting to accumulate enough cash for a full share of stock.

So essentially, a dividend reinvestment plan is offered by companies directly, allowing investors to bypass brokerages, and immediately re-invests dividends rather than paying them out in cash.

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dividendreinvestmentplan.asp) also gives a straighforward definition:

> A plan offered by a corporation that allows investors to reinvest their cash dividends by purchasing additional shares or fractional shares on the dividend payment date.
>
> A DRIP is an excellent way to increase the value of your investment. Most DRIPs allow you to buy shares commission free and at a significant discount to the current share price. Most DRIPS don't allow reinvestments much lower than $10.

I had a hard time finding a comprehensive listing of companies that offered DRPs (or DRIPs), but [MyDollarPlan.com](http://www.mydollarplan.com/what-is-a-dividend-reinvestment-plan/) offers these suggestions:

> **Finding a Dividend Reinvestment Plan:**
>
> [Computershare](https://www-us.computershare.com/Investor/Plans/buyshares.asp?bhjs=1&fla=1) offers one-stop shopping for hundreds of dividend reinvestment plans. They offer a searchable list that can be filtered to easily find a dividend reinvestment plan that fits your needs.
>
> You can also use [OneShare](http://www.oneshare.com/?AID=1110872&PID=2800886).
>
> Probably the best way to find out if a company offers a dividend reinvestment plan is to visit the company website. Most companies have an Investor Relations area that will highlight the various options available to shareowners. For example: Coca-Cola, Disney, and Wal-Mart.

Hope this helps!
@YMCbuzz

Comment: If the company gives a dividend and the investor decides to buy additional shares with that money..then that is re investment, right? Why does the company need to offer a 'plan' to enable the investor to reinvest?

Comment: @Kaushik Investors CAN reinvest dividends without buying stock directly from the company. But as the answer says, DRIPs **allow investors to bypass brokerages... and buy shares commission-free at a significant discount to current share price**. The incentive to the company to offer a DRIP (not all do, by the way), is that it lets them have the certainty of a known number of shares having dividends reinvested rather than needing to be paid out. There may be other reasons as well, but that deserves a question all of its own!